# unexpected hash code after using google tag manager in nextjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I'm using nextjs and add google tag manager by script

```
<script
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
   __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-P35C2ZJ');`,
            }}
          ></script>
```

but after adding this script in _documetn.js, an unexpected hash appears at the bottom page after the body tag

[image]

and here

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox what is the problem?

Comment: Just curious, because you could pass the js as a children string of the script component.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the @evolutionxbox curiosity is reasonable. There is no reason to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

To add it to your `_document.js`, please read [the docs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) first and then follow it.

For example:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx:any) {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
        return { ...initialProps }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head>
                    <script>
                        {
                            function ({w, d, s, l, i}: any) {
                                w[l] = w[l] || [];
                                w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' });
                                var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
                                j.async = true; j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
                                f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
                            }
                        }
                        (window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXX');
                    </script>
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style={{ display: 'none', visibility: 'hidden' }}></iframe></noscript>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        )
    }
}

export default MyDocument
```

_Note: I have tried it in TypeScript. If you are using Javascript, edit it as needed.